# Constructing a simple dataframe (DADA2 Pipeline transition to Phyloseq)

Tags: r, phyloseq

I successfully completed the DADA2 Pipeline Tutorial (https://benjjneb.github.io/dada2/tutorial.html) using my own data but have gotten stuck with the transition to Phyloseq. I need to construct a simple data.frame from the information encoded in the filenames. This is the code provided in the tutorial.

```
#Make a data.frame holding the sample data
samples.out <- rownames(seqtab.nochim)
subject <- sapply(strsplit(samples.out, "D"), `[`, 1)
gender <- substr(subject,1,1)
subject <- substr(subject,2,999)
day <- as.integer(sapply(strsplit(samples.out, "D"), `[`, 2))
samdf <- data.frame(Subject=subject, Gender=gender, Day=day)
samdf$When <- "Early"
samdf$When[samdf$Day>100] <- "Late"
rownames(samdf) <- samples.out
```

Mine should be more simple than this because I don't have time as a factor. I just have six treatment groups.

This is me trying to figure it out.

```
#Make a data.frame holding the sample data
samples.out <- rownames(seqtab.nochim)

#create vector with the treatments
trtmt <- c("EM", "EP", "EM", "AR37", "NEA2", "AR1", "AR37", "NEA2", "EP", "NEA2", "EP", "EM", "AR37", "EP", "NEA2", "Ctrl", "Ctrl", "AR37", "EP", "AR37", "AR37", "EP", "AR1", "AR1", "EP", "EM", "EM", "AR37", "AR1", "EM", "AR37", "NEA2", "AR1", "Ctrl", "EP", "Ctrl", "EP", "AR37", "AR37")

#Add a new column to the samples.out dataframe 
samples.out_2 <- samples.out
samples.out_2 <- cbind(samples.out, new_col = trtmt)

#Rename columns
colnames(samples.out_2)[colnames(samples.out_2) == "samples.out"] <- "Sample"
colnames(samples.out_2)[colnames(samples.out_2) == "new_col"] <- "Treatment"

#Head of my samples.out_2 data frame (I have a total of 39 samples and 6 treatment groups)
Sample Treatment
193    EM
194    EP
196    EM
197    AR37
198    NEA2

#Still stuck with how to make this relevant to my metadata!
sample <- sapply(strsplit(samples.out_2, "D"), `[`, 1) #what does the "D" mean (I think it has to do with the mouse dataset used in the tutorial)? However, I am not sure what I need to pull from my data.frame. Also, What does '[' mean? I know the meanings for operators like [], (), etc., but not for a single one in quotes.
treatment <- substr(sample,1,39) #I don't understand what I am trying to extract or change
sample <- substr(sample,2,999) #I don't understand what I am trying to extract or change
samdf <- data.frame(Sample=sample, Treatment=treatment)
rownames(samdf) <- samples.out
```

If anyone has gone through this tutorial with their own data, and understood this transition, I would appreciate your insights. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a data frame with your metadata in an object called `samdf` (to do as in the tutorial).
In the tutorial, the sequences have their metadata encoded in their filename (which doesn't seem to be the case with your data):

for example for the first

F3D0 : Gender (F)-Subject-(no3)-Day (D0)

The lines of code to define `Subject`, `Gender` and `Day` in the tutorial are not relevant for your data.

```
subject <- sapply(strsplit(samples.out, "D"), `[`, 1) # define subject as beginning of the filename string up to D
gender <- substr(subject,1,1) #gets first letter for the gender
subject <- substr(subject,2,999) #remove gender to actually get the subject number
day <- as.integer(sapply(strsplit(samples.out, "D"), `[`, 2)) #define day
```

The last two lines are important, one to create your dataframe with your metadata, the second to assign the same rownames as in `seqtab.nochim`, so that you can build your phyloseq object further down the pipeline.
Make sure `samdf` and `seqtab.nochim` have the same number of rows:

```
isTRUE(dim(seqtab.nochim)[1] == dim(samdf)[1]) #should be true
```